# Integrate Cucumber with Jenkins using Gradle tasks

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, cucumber

I am an intern currently working in a big company.
In my test automation project (github), there is two test by two different teams in the same project, so there's two Cucumber JUnit file. I don't know how to run both separately, so I search, and the way that I currently did is to split them into two Gradle tasks.

```
task ivtTest() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['--plugin', 'html:cucumber.html', '--plugin', 'pretty','--plugin', 'json:cucumber.json', '--glue', '<glue location>', '<feature file location>']
        }
    }
}
task svtTest() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['--plugin', 'html:cucumber.html', '--plugin', 'pretty','--plugin', 'json:cucumber.json', '--glue', '<glue location>', '<feature file location>']
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to integrate this with Jenkins. I read the documentation here: [Continuos Build - Cucumber](https://docs.cucumber.io/guides/continuous-integration/#jenkins). The way it does is :

```
node {
    stage('Generate HTML report') {
        cucumber buildStatus: 'UNSTABLE',
                fileIncludePattern: '**/*.json',
                trendsLimit: 10,
                classifications: [
                    [
                        'key': 'Browser',
                        'value': 'Firefox'
                    ]
                ]
    }
}
```

I guess it runs the JUnit file? It doesn't show a way to use Gradle tasks instead. 
Since I have two JUnit, will it run both of the JUnit? Is there a way to use the Gradle tasks instead?
I'm sorry if this is a stupid question. I'm still new to all of this. I don't learn this at my University.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the Gradle tasks in the pipeline using something like the following:

```
stages {
    stage('Gradle tasks') {
        steps {
            sh 'bash ./gradlew ivtTest'
            sh 'bash ./gradlew svtTest'
        }
    }
    stage('Generate HTML report') {
        cucumber buildStatus: 'UNSTABLE',
                fileIncludePattern: '**/*.json',
                trendsLimit: 10,
                classifications: [
                    [
                        'key': 'Browser',
                        'value': 'Firefox'
                    ]
                ]
    }
}
```

This is if Jenkins is running on Linux server, if it is running on Windows, replace `sh` with `bat`.